# Install Cairo and Canvas on Windows 8 machine

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, cairo

I'm having a problem with installing Canvas on my Windows 8 machine.

I need to use hog-descriptor, and for that I need Canvas to be installed but, when I try to 'npm install canvas' I get this error:

```
c:\users\omri\node_modules\canvas\src\Canvas.h(19): fatal error C1083: Cannot 
open include file: 'cairo/cairo.h': No such file or directory (..\src\CanvasPatt

gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:
12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\iolo\scipy-0.14.0\node_modules\canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.33
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! canvas@1.1.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.1.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the canvas package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls canvas
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "canvas"
npm ERR! cwd C:\iolo\scipy-0.14.0
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have Visual C++ 2010 or newer installed?

Comment: yes, i do have it installed. @mscdex

Comment: Which version do you have installed?

Comment: microsoft visual c++ 2010

Comment: Did you also install the [Windows 8 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363)?

Comment: You may also need [this fix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2736182) when using Windows 8.

Comment: c:\users\omri\node_modules\canvas\src\Canvas.h(19): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cairo/cairo.h': No such file or directory (..\src\CanvasPatt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the missing cairo library error, follow the directions to install cairo in the `canvas` module's wiki [here](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Windows#installing-cairo-library).

Answer (score 0):

Canvas is hard-coded somewhere (or maybe taking cues from node-gyp) to only accept a GTK2 directory that's named **GTK**. So it seems to go smoothest to just extract GTK2 to `C:\GTK` otherwise you'll be chasing missing header files.